# Selecting only check marked rows in a different table - Mac Numbers

Tags: macos, cocoa, macros, iwork, apple-numbers

I have a table in Mac Numbers which has a column with checkbox. I am trying to copy only those rows in a second table which are check marked.

I also want to extend this solution to multiple tables; I will have multiple tables having a column with checkbox. I want to copy all those rows into a single table which are check marked.

I tried with LOOPUP function but it didn't help.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out in 2 steps -

1. Used IF condition to put column data if checkbox is checked else put "NA".
2. Then put a filter on the new table to filter out all rows which has that column with values "NA".